Change multiple item values at once, by a given fraction
I have to manage an e-catalog and I need to change the price values of it
by a percentage of the original values given by my supplier.
the xml file has this kind of structure, but over 1000 items long:
<E_CATALOG>

<item>      
<MATERIAL_NUM>000000000000004720</MATERIAL_NUM>
<MATERIAL_DESCR>ΑΝΑΛΩΣ HP INK NO 45 BLACK 42ML</MATERIAL_DESCR>
<EAN_UPC>88698603659</EAN_UPC>
<PART_NUMBER>51645AE</PART_NUMBER>
<SUPPLIER>HP</SUPPLIER>
<CATEGORY>Αναλώσιμα</CATEGORY>
<SUBCATEGORY>Μελάνια</SUBCATEGORY>
<IMAGE_URL>~/getmetafile/483396b2-38ea-4cb1-9856-877dc0b3b066/product-4720-main.aspx</IMAGE_URL>
<PRICE>65.05</PRICE>
<ATP_QUANTITY>0</ATP_QUANTITY>
</item>

<item>
<MATERIAL_NUM>000000000000008879</MATERIAL_NUM>
<MATERIAL_DESCR>ΑΝΑΛΩΣ  EPSON A4 PAPER PHOTO MATT 100SH</MATERIAL_DESCR>
<EAN_UPC>10343812017</EAN_UPC>
<PART_NUMBER>C13S041061</PART_NUMBER>
<SUPPLIER>EPSON</SUPPLIER>
<CATEGORY>Είδη γραφείου</CATEGORY>
<SUBCATEGORY>Χαρτικά Αναλώσιμα</SUBCATEGORY>
<IMAGE_URL>~/getmetafile/65f7ee5b-7ad7-43e8-a476-896c72dff8c4/product-8879-main.aspx</IMAGE_URL>
<PRICE>18.10</PRICE>
<ATP_QUANTITY>6</ATP_QUANTITY>
</item>

<item>
<MATERIAL_NUM>000000000000010228</MATERIAL_NUM>
<MATERIAL_DESCR>ΑΝΑΛΩΣ EPSON RIBBON BLACK C13S015022</MATERIAL_DESCR>
<EAN_UPC>10343600447</EAN_UPC>
<PART_NUMBER>C13S015022</PART_NUMBER>
<SUPPLIER>EPSON</SUPPLIER>
<CATEGORY>Αναλώσιμα</CATEGORY>
<SUBCATEGORY>Μελανοταινίες</SUBCATEGORY>
<IMAGE_URL>~/getmetafile/c2c00f78-b088-4690-8143-33f4fb4233f5/product-10228-main.aspx</IMAGE_URL>
<PRICE>9.05</PRICE>
<ATP_QUANTITY>0</ATP_QUANTITY>
</item>

</E_CATALOG>

I tried some suggestions I found online for a different project but somewhat similar aproach.
No luck so far. Using Notepad++

What is the expected output? You've just posted XML

If you are discounting every item by the same value, then you only need to modify the price when displaying it to a potential purchaser. So there  is no need to change the XML, just calciulate the discounted price when creating a listing.

I need a solution, thought maybe a piece of code, to open/read the values of that xml file, asking the user about what percentage of price value to add/remove on all items, then apply the multiplication and save an updated file. It's for an e-shop project.

He is a powershell script that will work
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$inputFilename = 'c:\temp\test.xml'
$outputFilename = 'c:\temp\test1.xml'
$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($inputFilename)

$multiplier = [decimal]0.50
$prices = $doc.Descendants('PRICE')
foreach($price in $prices)
{
   $price.Value = $multiplier * [decimal]$price.Value
}
$doc.Save($outputFilename)


Seems to work. Much appresiated!
Thank you so much!!

If you want to do this in Python, you can make good use of the standard xml module as follows:
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

XMLFILE = "foo.xml"
PCHANGE = 10 # 10% increase

tree = ET.parse(XMLFILE)

# get all items
for item in tree.getroot().iter("item"):
    # ensure that there's a PRICE element
    if (pe := item.find("PRICE")) is not None:
        # ...and that it has some associated text
        if pt := pe.text:
            try:
                price = float(pt) * (1 + (PCHANGE / 100))
                pe.text = f"{price:.2f}"
            except ValueError:
                pass # could not convert the text to float

tree.write(XMLFILE)

